# What generates the structurel.sql file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have 3 different schemas in one Rails application. My preparation of the test database using `rake db:test:prepare` fails with:

```
psql:/Users/me/myapp/db/structure.sql:7417: ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO schema_migrations (version) VALUES ('20131213203...
```

That's because it is not proper setting the Postgres search_path before doing all the insertions to the `schema_migrations` table. I haven't messed with this code in about 8 months and can't remember what I did. I haven't the faintest idea of how I even got those other schema to dump.

Comment: I don't thing it is a standard setup. Did you ask the person who worked on this project before you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I needed by doing two things:

- Overriding the `purge` task under `db:test` in AR's `railties` to call a custom `drop_database_objects` method.
- Using a little-known attribute in my database.yml:   `schema_search_path: public`

The first thing lets me drop only the database objects I want, leaving my other support databases intact.

The second thing just creates the structure from my main database, and doesn't try to create the structure from the other databases. It looks like a bug in that it `structure:dump` doesn't set the schema search path appropriately at the end of the structure.sql script, right before the inserts into the `schema_migrations` table in a multi-schema instance. These fixes make that not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `rake db:structure:dump` and / or `rake db:schema:dump` and try re-running rake db:test:prepare.  The former should create the structure.sql and the later the schema.db